# Is there any way I can style the nested component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Here's my code.

```
/*Default Styled Component*/

import styled from "styled-components";
export const MenuWrapper = styled.ul`
border: 1px solid blue;
`

export const MenuList = styled.li`
color: blue;
`

export const Menu = (
  <MenuWrapper>
   <MenuList>1</MenuList>
   <MenuList>2</MenuList>
   <MenuList>3</MenuList>
  </MenuWrapper>
);




/* This is where I tried to restyle */

import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  Menu,
  MenuWrapper,
  MenuList,
} from '../src/components/Menu.style';

const StyledMenu = styled(Menu)`
${MenuWrapper} {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
${MenuList} {
  color: green;
}
```

What I want to do is to create a default styled component with multiple elements in it and restyle according to my needs by using 'styled(Menu)' and adding ${MenuWrapper} ${MenuList} as selectors for nested elements but they all don't seem to work... Anyone can help..? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues here, but in the first place it seems like the problem is caused by the fact that you're not attaching the `className` prop to what's inside `Menu`.

See https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component and this Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-carlos-vt165s